# How to change text from another activity?

Tags: java, android, html, android-activity, textview

I am creating an Android app - using Android Studio.

The app launches in MainActivity.java which fetches activity_main.xml . On activity_main, the user can select one of 3 buttons. No matter which button they select, it will take them to the SAME layout - primary_layout.xml and the Java class associated with that is PrimaryClass.java .

I have a placeholder in primary_layout. I want this placeholder (id: placeholder) to change according to what button was previously selected.

Eg. If Button 1 (id: button1) is clicked, then the placeholder must say “Button 1 was clicked.”

Or let’s say Button 2 (id: button2) was clicked, then the placeholder must say “Button 2 was clicked”. And the same goes for Button 3.
I have created an intent to open PrimaryClass but I'm not too sure how to code the intent for when the button is clicked. I just don’t know how to change the text of the placeholder, depending on which button the user has clicked. I’ve tried using an ‘if statement’ but it doesn’t seem to work.
Or instead of creating another activity, should I rather create a fragment, and if I should, how would I code the fragment in this particular app?
I have attached images and code to better understand.

[image]

[image]

And here is my code of my classes and layout files:

MainActivity:

```
package com.msp.exampleapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

activity_main:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.msp.exampleapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="clickedButton1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="clickedButton2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="clickedButton3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PrimaryClass:

```
package com.msp.exampleapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PrimaryClass extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.primary_layout);

    }
}
```

primary_layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="{holder}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/placeholder" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use listener interface or EVENT BUS

Comment: How would I intend to do that with my specific project?

Comment: for that, just pass text value with intent.putextra(); and get that value in next activity

Comment: @msp Read this article hope this helps.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first Activity must look like this:

```
 package com.msp.exampleapplication;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button button1,button2,button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("message","Button 1 selected");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("message","Button 2 selected");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("message","Button 3 selected");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }

  }
```

Code the second activity as below:

```
package com.msp.exampleapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PrimaryClass extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView placeholder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.primary_layout);
    placeholder=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);

    placeholder.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));

}
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Your code works and runs the way I want it to! Thank you so much, I was trying to solve this problem for several weeks now! I really appreciate it so much! Have a great day!

Comment: @MSP .. Glad that it worked. Also, I'd really appreciate an Upvote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution of your problem. You have to use Intent to make action in another activity.

Code for MainActivity, create a intent on each button click like below

```
 button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("button_text", "Button 1 Clicked");
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Same for button 2 and 3

```
button_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("button_text", "Button 2 Clicked");
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

button_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrimaryClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("button_text", "Button 3 Clicked");
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now in PrimaryClass use this code inside onCreate Method

```
  String btn_text;
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (bundle != null) {
   btn_text = bundle.getString("button_text");
 }
```

Now set text on lable

```
textView.setText(btn_text);
```

Hope you understand this, if not let me know, I'll help you.

Comment: Hi, I have pasted your code in and it's coming up with multiple errors with 'View v' and 'onClickListener' and '@Override'

Comment: You have to import this file by pressing "Alt+Enter"

Comment: Add this in your code at top -
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: Welcome, if it helps accept answer and don't forget to up-vote answer...